# Updating one Map key from another map Value

Tags: java, maps

I have one HashMap called `list` which contains a few `key/values`. I've got another HashMap called `modify` which contains another set of `key/values`.

Basically the `modify` hashmap is supposed to contain a key (or keys) that match to a key in `list`, and I want to update the key in `list` to be the value that matches that key in `modify`.

I tried:

```
iter = modifyList.entrySet().iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
     list.replace(iter.next().getKey(), iter.next().getValue());
}
```

However you run in to the issue where when you call `iter.next().getKey()` it obviously iterates forward so now the value that I want is no longer in `next()` and is instead in `current`. However I can't find any way to access what is in `current`

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try iterating over the key and value:

```
modifyList.forEach(list::replace);
```

Which is the same as:

```
modifyList.forEach((k, v) -> list.replace(k, v));
```

Now if you're looking to remap the keys themselves, you can use a combination of `put` and `remove`:

```
modifyList.forEach((k, v) -> list.put(v, list.remove(k)));
```

Comment: Or `list::replace`.

Comment: This may be a stupid question but should that line still be in my iterator loop, or just simply the one line on it's own?

Comment: A line on its own

Comment: It looks like when I run this the value of the `list` key is being updated with the value from the `modifyList` value where the keys match. Which is close, however what I'm looking for is for the key of the `list` key that matches the key of the `modifyList` to be updated to the value of the corresponding value in `modifyList` if that makes sense.

Comment: Update the iteration function to match your needs as above.